# Alinear textos dentro de un div

Tags: css

mi problema es que quiero centrar un texto para que quede centrado dentro de un div,como en ésta imagen: https://gyazo.com/510e90605dbc9c23c0a36aa563f8ef00

¿Alguien me ayuda?

Comment: Hola Big Boss, Por favor investiga un poco mas antes hacer una pregunta, si quieres centrar un texto a base de un div por favor utiliza la propiedad css TEXT-ALIGN: CENTER; Te dejo u  link de ejemplo con el que te puedes orientar mejor.   https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.asp

Comment: Lo hice,pero se mantiene en la parte superior,puedo usar text align varias veces?

Comment: Bienvenido Big Boss, te invito a que visites esta sección [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que te des una idea de cómo funciona SO.

Answer (score 0):

Con un `text-align: center` debería funcionar.

```css
.container {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 50%;
  height: 300px;
  
 }
 
 .centrado {
  text-align: center;
  
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="centrado">Esto es el texto alineado en el centro</p>
  <p>No estoy centrado</p>

</div>
```

En cualquier caso, si no te funciona, lo que puedes hacer es añadírselo al `parent`, aunque eso haga que se cambie todo el contenido de dentro, te aseguras de que se centra el contenido que hay dentro.